# SQLite Database Browser "Temp Table already exists"

Tags: android, sqlite

I was following [this tutorial](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) in order to integrate a pre made database to my Android App.

Everything was going well until it asked me to rename my Primary Key Field to "_id". Well for one I don't have a PK (I know it's bad DB practice), and two, the PK is not an integer type, giving a type mismatch error. Now, I tried to rename one of my fields (non integer) to "_id" and now I can't rename it back. Also, I tried removing an extra field that I don't need and it gives me this error:

> Error removing field. Message from database engine:  table TEMP_TABLE already exists

or this

> Error editing field. Message from database engine:  table TEMP_TABLE already exists

Not quite sure how to work this out since I'm not familiar with using the terminal to work with databases. I tried looking around and there are no extra unaccounted for tables so I don't know where these are coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get [SQLite Manager](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/) (a FireFox extension) to work with your DB on your desktop, it's free and works pretty well.  It's got a fairly reasonable GUI... so it's much more friendly than using the command line.

And yeah, android wants a primary key field called "_id" and it needs to be an integer.  It seems they based all of their list-type widgets upon this premise.  I can tell you from personal experience that the ListView widget won't work if you don't have an _id column in the cursor!

Comment: Excellent, I'd never heard of it, it looks good too (and honestly I hate having to start FireFox before being able to use the db editor... there's probably a way to launch it without doing that, but I've been too lazy to figure it out).  Downloading now!

Comment: Sadly, sqliteexpert isn't available for Mac.